# How does pandas.merge scale?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have two dataframes **A** and **B**. A consumes about 15 times more memory and has about 30 times more rows than B. However, if I merge A to itself it takes only about 15 seconds, whereas merging B to itself takes about 15 minutes (pandas version 1.1.5).

```
# this chain of operations takes about 15 seconds with A
(A # with B here and in the line below it takes about 15 minutes
 .merge(A, how='left', indicator=True)  
 .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
 .drop(columns='_merge')
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Does anyone know how merges scale in pandas? Why is the merge of the large dataframe with itself so much faster than that of the small one with itself?

---

More details on the two dataframes:

**Dataframe A:**

```
RangeIndex: 7250117 entries, 0 to 7250116
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column         Dtype  
---  ------         -----  
 0   Order_ID       int64  
 1   Color          object 
 2   Size           object 
 3   Country        object 
 4   pieces_demand  float64
 5   count          int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 331.9+ MB
```

**DataFrame B:**

```
RangeIndex: 234805 entries, 0 to 234804
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------                 --------------   -----  
 0   Order_ID               234805 non-null  int64  
 1   Color                  234805 non-null  object 
 2   Size                   234805 non-null  object 
 3   pieces_demand          234805 non-null  float64
 4   pieces_ordered         234805 non-null  float64
 5   Size_Index             234805 non-null  int64  
 6   dist_demand            234805 non-null  float64
 7   dist_ordered           234805 non-null  float64
 8   dist_discrete_demand   234805 non-null  float64
 9   dist_discrete_ordered  234805 non-null  float64
 10  count                  234805 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(6), int64(3), object(2)
memory usage: 19.7+ MB
```

Comment: Since you aren't specifying any `on=` conditions it's trying to merge on every value. My guess is there's a slowdown with 10 vs 5 as well as the complexity of many float column.

Comment: Yeah that's the only thing I can think of as well. However, I did not expect such a strong slow down. Made me wonder, if anything is known about the scaling behaviour of pandas.merge. Haven't found anything on that on the web yet.